# manifest missing classpath when built with mvn assembly:single

Tags: java, eclipse, maven-2, pom.xml

I am building my project using maven and eclipse. I am using the command mvn assembly:single which runs quite happily. However when I attempt to run the jar using:

```
java Iris-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: target/Iris-1/0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies/jar
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: target.Iris-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-    dependencies.jar
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Also the manifest doesn't contain the class path. The manifest that is produced looks like

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Built-By: maxgarfinkel
Build-Jdk: 1.6.0_29
Created-By: Apache Maven
Main-Class: com.maxgarfinkel.iris.commandLine.CommandLineTools
Archiver-Version: Plexus Archiver
```

and the pom looks like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.maxgarfinkel.iris</groupId>
<artifactId>Iris</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Iris</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>com.maxgarfinkel.iris.commandLine.CommandLineTools</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.swinglabs</groupId>
        <artifactId>swing-layout</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlrpc-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
        <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.5</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-graph-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop</groupId>
        <artifactId>hadoop</artifactId>
        <version>0.20.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-commons-cli-1.2</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli-1.2</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-commons-codec-1.3</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-codec-1.3</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-commons-el-1.0</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-el-1.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-commons-httpclient-3.0.1</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient-3.0.1</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-commons-net-1.4.1</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net-1.4.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-core-3.1.1</groupId>
        <artifactId>core-3.1.1</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-hsqldb-1.8.0.10</groupId>
        <artifactId>hsqldb-1.8.0.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.0.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-jasper-compiler-5.5.12</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-compiler-5.5.12</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-jasper-runtime-5.5.12</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasper-runtime-5.5.12</artifactId>
        <version>5.5.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-jets3t-0.6.1</groupId>
        <artifactId>jets3t-0.6.1</artifactId>
        <version>0.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-jetty-6.1.14</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-6.1.14</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-jetty-util-6.1.14</groupId>
        <artifactId>jetty-util-6.1.14</artifactId>
        <version>6.1.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-kfs-0.2.2</groupId>
        <artifactId>kfs-0.2.2</artifactId>
        <version>0.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-oro-2.0.8</groupId>
        <artifactId>oro-2.0.8</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-slf4j-api-1.4.3</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api-1.4.3</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12-1.4.3</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-xmlenc-0.52</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlenc-0.52</artifactId>
        <version>0.52</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>hadoop-zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>colt</groupId>
        <artifactId>colt</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.inamik.utils.tableformatter-0.9.1</groupId>
        <artifactId>com.inamik.utils.tableformatter-0.9.1</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>Voronoi</groupId>
        <artifactId>voronoi</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-algorithms</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-visualization</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jung</groupId>
        <artifactId>jung-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.explodingpixels</groupId>
        <artifactId>mac_widgets</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.miglayout</groupId>
        <artifactId>miglayout</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

1. How can I get the classpath to show up?
2. WIll that make the jar runnable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do this

```
java -jar Iris-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar.
```

For more information see this link
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/run.html

Also there is no need for the manifest to contain the classpath (I think).

Comment: Doh! feel a bit stupid for that one! However it has only marginally improved matters. now I get:  Exception in thread "main" 

    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/maxgarfinkel/iris/commandLine/CommandLineTools

which is in my jar at that location.

Comment: Can u open the jar and really check the class exists in the correct package or not ?

Comment: Thanks. thats fixed it. It wasn't there. Had to call 
    mvn package
to get the right jar made.